# How to get last related update and second last related update

Tags: mysql, sql, sugarcrm

I have 3 tables : `opportunities`, `tr_opportunity_updates` and
`opportunities_tr_opportunity_updates_1_c`. The latter relates `opportunities` to `opportunity_updates`.

I would like to get 3 columns the first is the opportunity name the second is last update made to the opportunity and third ise the second last update made to the opportunity.

I am trying to get the following output:

```
  -----------------------------------------------
  Opportunity | Last_Update | Second_Last update 
  -----------------------------------------------
  Opp1        | update      | second bla bla     
  -----------------------------------------------
  Opp2        | Lastest up. | second bla bla
```

I have a query which gets the Opportunity name and the last update but I don’t know how to get the get the second last update also and add it in as another column. Would this be a sub query? if so how:

```
  SELECT opportunities.name AS Opportunity, tr_opportunity_updates.description AS Last_Update
  FROM opportunities
  LEFT JOIN opportunities_tr_opportunity_updates_1_c ON opportunities_tr_opportunity_updates_1_c.opportunities_tr_opportunity_updates_1opportunities_ida = opportunities.id
  LEFT JOIN tr_opportunity_updates ON opportunities_tr_opportunity_updates_1_c.opportunities_tr_opportunity_updates_1tr_opportunity_updates_idb = tr_opportunity_updates.id
  WHERE opportunities.deleted = 0
  GROUP BY opportunities.name
  LIMIT 0 , 30
```

I tried to implement an sql fiddle for this but my tables and data are far to large with many irreverent fields, but all the info relevant to this question above query apart from date_created which is in all tables and may be requried for getting the second last update?

Answer (score 0):

Since nobody even tried to help I will post my own answer:

```
 SELECT oppa.name AS Opportunity, tr_opportunity_updates.description AS Last_Update,
 (SELECT tou.description FROM opportunities oppb
 LEFT JOIN opportunities_tr_opportunity_updates_1_c ON opportunities_tr_opportunity_updates_1_c.opportunities_tr_opportunity_updates_1opportunities_ida = oppb.id LEFT JOIN tr_opportunity_updates tou ON opportunities_tr_opportunity_updates_1_c.opportunities_tr_opportunity_updates_1tr_opportunity_updates_idb = tou.id
 WHERE oppb.deleted =0 AND tou.deleted =0 AND oppb.id = oppa.id
 ORDER BY tou.date_modified Desc LIMIT 1,1) AS Second_Last_Update
 FROM opportunities oppa
 LEFT JOIN opportunities_tr_opportunity_updates_1_c ON opportunities_tr_opportunity_updates_1_c.opportunities_tr_opportunity_updates_1opportunities_ida = oppa.id
 LEFT JOIN tr_opportunity_updates ON opportunities_tr_opportunity_updates_1_c.opportunities_tr_opportunity_updates_1tr_opportunity_updates_idb = tr_opportunity_updates.id
 WHERE oppa.deleted =0 AND tr_opportunity_updates.deleted =0
  GROUP BY oppa.name
```